# WebDriver Wait does not work properly

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying not to wait until the whole page is loaded. As  far as I'm concerned `WebDriverWait` should help with that so I've tried put it into my code but there is probably something that I don't know because it raises `TimeoutException` although I can see the tag.

```
self.driver.get('http://www.quoka.de/')
self.wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search1')))
self.driver.find_element_by_id("search1").send_keys('nachhilfe')
self.driver.find_element_by_id('searchbutton').click()
```

So it opens Firefox, then wait until page is loaded. This is the tag I'm looking for:

```
<input id="search1" name="search1" class="form-control" placeholder="Was suchst du?" value="" type="text">
```

Firefox has this tag already loaded but it still waits for the whole page. Do you have any advises?

EDIT: As far as I'm concerned this line `self.wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search1')))` should make Firefox to wait until the tag is visible and right after this tag is loaded it should continue with another lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
self.driver.get('http://www.quoka.de/')
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search1')))
self.driver.find_element_by_id("search1").send_keys('nachhilfe')
self.driver.find_element_by_id('searchbutton').click()
```

invisibility_of_element_located waits for an element to be either **invisible** or **not present** in the DOM!
As far as I understood your Question you want the exact opposite. So try presence_of_element_located instead.

Be aware that find_element_by_id also takes some time. So there won't be an instant send_keys as soon as the element is visible to you as the user.

to measure this time you could experiment a bit:

```
import time

start = time.time()

self.driver.get('http://www.quoka.de/')
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search1')))

end = time.time()

print end-start

start = time.time()

element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("search1")

end = time.time()

print end-start

element.send_keys('nachhilfe')
self.driver.find_element_by_id('searchbutton').click()
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not work neither. If I put on the beggining of the code this: self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search1')))
        self.driver.get('http://www.quoka.de/') It doesn't even load the page.

Comment: no you need to put it at the exact same position as before, updated my answer

Comment: Ok, I changed the code. So now, it shouldn't be waiting until the whole self.driver.get(http://www.quoka.de/)  is loaded. It has to wait until "search1" is loaded. But I can clearly see that "search1" form is loaded several seconds before it send_keys and stuff.

Comment: "several seconds" is less than before? you need to be aware that find_element_by_id also takes time. So you have to consider that first it waits until element is present, THEN it starts to try to find your search1 element, and that might take some time depending on your DOM. So if you are now faster then before, you got your solution

Comment: It is slower than without that. Weird.

Comment: then I guess it's really the find_element_by_id method that takes longer than you expect. You have to consider that also within the until method find_element is invoked periodically. that's why using the "right" wait.until method now really runs this method and thus takes longer than before